# JSON-Schema Type and Value Dependencies

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, ajv

Is it possible to change a field's schema - according to another's value?

Note: I'm using [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv)

Example using [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) (A non JSON-Schema validator):

```
const schema = {
    a: Joi.valid('x', 'y', 'z'),
    b: Joi.string()
        .when('a', { is: 'z', then: Joi.string(), otherwise: Joi.number() }),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way would be to have a $ref link depending on a [$data pointer](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/$data-(v5-proposal)).  Unfortunately, that isn't supported at the moment.

It's probably cleaner to do it using application logic, but if you're in a situation where you have to use a schema a more verbose way would be using [oneOf](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html?highlight=oneof#oneof).  In that scenario your schema would be something like:

```js
var ajv = new Ajv({
  $data: true
});
let schema = {
  oneOf: [ 
    {
      title: 'A is Z',
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        a: {
          type: 'string',
          enum: ['z']
        },
        b: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      title: 'A is not Z',
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        a: {
          type: 'string',
          not: {
            enum: ['z']
          }
        },
        b: {
          type: 'number'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};

let data = {
  a: 'z',
  b: '5'
};

ajv.validate(schema, data)

console.log('ERRORS: ', this.ajv.errors)
```

```html
<script data-require="ajv@*"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/5.3.0/ajv.bundle.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** Since you're using AJV you can also take advantage of the [AJV-Keywords module](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords).  It has a [if / then / else](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords#ifthenelse) operator that is currently [a proposal](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/180) for adding to the spec.